# Pass in the updated state to a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having some issues with updating the state of my child components using React and Redux.  I am relativley new to React so I may be going about this the wrong way.

This is essentially my usecase.  The ParentComponent is a "page" and it renders a custom Card component.  The Card component renders a MyTableComponent component (fixed-data-table).  I am passing the data into the MyTableComponent through "tableData={this.props.company}".  this.props.company is an array of objects.  The objects contain a "name" attirbute and a "users" attribute which is an array off all users associated with that company (pulled back from the database).  The table then loops over this.props.company and displays each company in the array.

Here is where my problem arrises.  When I click on a name from this.props.company list in the table, I am displaying a list of all users associated with that company.  Now, it works as expected for the first click, I click on an element in the table, and it lists the correct "users" associated with that company.  However, when I go back and click on another company form the table list, I recieve the same set of users as before.  After examining my logs, I see that my application state is being upated successfully, but my MyTableComponent always renders the users that are assoicated with the previoius company that was clicked on.  i.e its its rendering the old state and not the new state.

How do I go about solving this issue?  Is this a component lifescyle issue?  I want to make sure that "this.props.company" that gets passed into my MyTableComponent component is the new updated state.

Edit -

my component is updating, it's just updating to the previous state and not the new state.  My parent component is pulling in the new correct state, but its like my child component is being rendered before the new state can be passed into the component.  When I try running componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps), nextProps is the correct state.  But this.props.company is still the old state.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getMyCompanies(this.props.params.id);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <CardComponent configProps={{ height:'300px', width: '700px'cardItem: <MyTableComponent tableData={this.props.company} /> }} />
        )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { company: state.company }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, getMyCompanies)(ParentComponent);
```

Reducers:

```
import {
    FETCH_COMPANY,
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { company: {} };

export default function(state = { INITIAL_STATE }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case FETCH_COMPANY:
            return {...state, company: action.payload };

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Root Reducer

```
import companiesReducer from './companies_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  comapnies: companiesReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Can you paste your reducer?  99.9% of the time, "My component isn't updating" is because of direct mutation in your code.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering

Comment: you forgot a comma, after ```width: '700px'```

Comment: I must have missed the comma when I was copying over my code. It's not the issue.  And in regards to the reducers, my component is updating, it's just updating to the previous state and not the new state.  My parent component is pulling in the new correct state, but its like my child component is being rendered before the new state can be passed into the component.  When I try running componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps), nextProps is the correct state.  But this.props.company is still the old state.

Comment: can you provide a gist or repo

Comment: is it actual code? there is "comapnies" in combineReducers , but in mapStateToProps you slice :{ company: state.company }

Comment: No sorry its not actual code, the reducer is working as expected.  Like I said, I can see that the state is updating as expected by examining the logs generated by redux-logger.  The issue is that this.props.company is not being updated to the new state.

Comment: If you use React Dev Tools to trace out the props that are being passed from ParentComponent -> CardComponent -> MyTableComponent, are the props being passed down correctly? If you check when ParentComponent, CardComponent, and MyTableComponent are updating and when they're rendering (by inserting console.log statements in their componentWillUpdate and render methods), does that tell you anything?

Comment: "When I try running componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps), nextProps is the correct state. But this.props.company is still the old state." - I might not be understanding correctly, but isn't this expected behavior?  `componentWillReceiveProps` is supposed to run before the component re-renders after receiving props.  In this function, `this.props` refers to the old props, and `nextProps` refers to the new props that the component just received.